# TextBox displaying "0.00" or value with two decimals when I hit back or next on a wizard

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have this `decimal` set up:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please tell us your income")]
[Display(Name = "How much do you earn from all the income types you selected above?")]
[DataType(DataType.Currency)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:c}")]
public decimal IndivdualIncome { get; set; }
```

I am using `[Serializable]` on my Model. Using a ViewModel to bring this in to my view. Also using a multi-step wizard.

When I get to a step with this type of input (for capturing `decimal` values), the text box is empty and I can enter "1000". This is expected behavior.  However, say I click "Next" on the wizard and the next step has a similar text box (again, it's blank which is expected - call it "SpouseIncome"), but then if I do not enter any value and:

1. I hit "Back", then the "IndividualIncome" textbox will display the value as "1000.00"; and
2. If I then hit "Next", the "SpouseIncome" (which I left blank) now shows "0.00".

Is it my use of `decimal`, or possibly the attributes I am using?

Any help on how I can just have it display as either blank (no "0.00") or to take out the ".00" if a value was input previously is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use `"{0:N}"` which is number format or `"{0:g}"`, which is general number format instead currency format `"{0:c}"` you currently using.

Or you might want to consider custom number formatting to be very specific on what you looking for.
Something like this `{0:0,0}`, which is thousand separator, gives you 1,500.

More about string formats and custom number formatting [here](http://www.dotnetdawgs.com/?tag=/dataformatstring).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Changing `[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:c}")]` to `[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:N0}")]` should work